# To Load properties in ReactJS based on environment

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have few API calls to be done and URLS differ based environment the application is running. How do I try to load the URLS when application is running in a specific environment. This is a ReactJS based application.

I tried using .env & process.env.NODE_ENV but unable to load properties during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If your React project is based on [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#expanding-environment-variables-in-env), you need to prefix your variables by `REACT_APP_`. Otherwise, have a look at [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#dotenv).